# VSCode dash app.run_server(debug=True) not working - runs but says 'no module named <file name>' and does not load

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly-dash

debug=True is not working in VSCode. When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
> Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
> 
>  * Serving Flask app 'Test' (lazy loading)  * Environment: production 
> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production
> deployment.    Use a production WSGI server instead.  * Debug mode: on
> No module named Test
```

Test is the name of the file - if I change it to something else, like app.py or main.py, it just says that instead.

The code itself is super simple and taken directly from the Plotly Dash tutorial site, https://dash.plotly.com/layout:

> ```
> from dash import Dash, html, dcc 
> import plotly.express as px
> import pandas as pd
>
> app = Dash(__name__)
>
> # assume you have a "long-form" data frame
> # see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
> df = pd.DataFrame({
>     "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
>     "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
>     "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"] })
>
> fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")
>
> app.layout = html.Div(children=[
>     html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
>
>     html.Div(children='''
>         Dash: A web application framework for your data.
>     '''),
>
>     dcc.Graph(
>         id='example-graph',
>         figure=fig
>     ) ])
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     app.run_server(debug=True)
> ```

If I turn debug off, it does open up the dashboard in a new browser window. Debug=True has also worked for me in the past (well, the debugging hasn't, but the dashboard has opened up in the browser when I reload), the only thing that changed is that I'm now using Azure DevOps as a repo, but I can't think why that would make a difference?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you already have a dash-based application running on a separate screen? (Including this application)

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: It is reproduced according to the description, but there is no relevant problem. I think this may not be the problem of vscode. Have you tried to reinstall the extension or restart vscode

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I included the `debug=True` *and* ran the application with VSCode's Debugger.

**However, I was able to run my application normally through the terminal `> python app.py`**

Doesn't really solve it, as I have yet to find a way to properly debug my application, but a workaround I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the VSCode editor, open the folder where the `test.py` file is.
In case you need to use a module from a parent folder I use:

```py
import sys 
sys.path.append('path_to_parent_folder')
```

Then run the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it after adding `cwd` param to launch.json. It should be equal to `"${workspaceFolder}/RELATIVE_PATH_APP_FOLDER"`, where `RELATIVE_PATH_APP_FOLDER` is the relative path to your app.py script from the workspace folder.